# Qt: How to subtract two QSet of QString in case insensitivity mode

Tags: c++, qt, set, qstring, subtraction

I'm working on a logical problem using Qt.
I've got two QSets of QString:

```
QSet<QString> set1: [ "aaa", "BBB" ]
QSet<QString> set2: [ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd" ]
```

I want to subtract set1 from set2, so I use:

```
set2.subtract( set1 );
```

And I obtain:

```
set2: ["bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]
```

But in that case "bbb" isn't removed from set2, although set1 contains this record.
That's because the default QString::contains method (it is the method used by QSet::subtract) is case sensitive.

There is another QString::contains method which takes a parameter to define the case sensitivity mode, but I don't really see how I could use it.

Does anyone have an idea how to make a case insensitive subtraction between two QSet of QString, please?

Here's what I've tried so far:

**Transform both sets in uppercase** set2 is displayed in a list, so it won't be fancy if all items are in uppercase (or lowercase neither).

**Extend QSet class and override subtract method** I've tried to extend this class with a MyStringSet custom class, but I'm not very comfortable with Qt and this appears to me quite complicated.

Answer (score 8):

Qt container classes are largely compatible with STL. And std::set_difference allows specifying a comparator. This is very useful when you only need case insensitivity in some cases or don't want to mess with deriving standard types:

```
struct qstring_compare_i
{
    bool operator()(const QString & x, const QString y) const
    { return QString::compare(x, y, Qt::CaseInsensitive) < 0; }
};

static QSet<QString> substract_sets(const QSet<QString> & qs1, const QSet<QString> & qs2)
{
    std::set<QString> r;
    std::set_difference(qs1.begin(), qs1.end(), qs2.begin(), qs2.end(), std::inserter(r, r.end()), qstring_compare_i());

    QSet<QString> result;
    for(std::set<QString>::iterator i=r.begin();i!=r.end();++i) {
        result << *i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way would be to sub-class the QString like this and override the comparators, in the example below I've done the equality operator:

```
  class QStringInsensitive: public QString
  {
     bool operator==(const QString& other) const
     {
        return (0 == this->compare(other, Qt::CaseInsensitive));
     }
  };
  QSet< QStringInsensitive > set;
```

Comment: Thanks, as I say I'm not quite comfortable with Qt. With your solution, I can't insert any QString in my QSet<QStringInsensitive>. So I think I need to keep my QSet<QString> but I should cast my QString into QStringInsensitive.

Comment: What do you think? Because, I don't know if I must create a QStringInsensitive(const QString&) constructor, or casting.

Comment: Hi, I've tried unsuccessfully this solution :

QString *entry;
QStringInsensitive *entryInsensitive = qobject_cast<QStringInsensitive *>(entry);

I've got this error:
no matching function for call to 'qobject_cast(QString*&)'

I can't find any example on internet, or in the doc, to make this cast.

May need some help here, please :)

Comment: Ok, the error is quite obvious: QString doesn't inherit QObject. I'm really confuse now. Isn't QObject the parent class of all Qt classes?

Comment: Short answer is no. Longer answer is that only classes that need to be handled signals & slots will be a Qt object. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html

Comment: Ok, so what could I use to cast from QString to QStringInsensitive, please?

Comment: Use this conversion constructor:
    QStringInsensitive(QString q):
        QString(q)
    {
    }